# How do I add something to the preamble in LyX?

Tags: lyx, preamble

I'm trying to add something to the preamble, but don't know how. I tried `Insert -> Latex Code` and just picked places on my article, but I guess they were never in the preamble? I guess I cannot just put code into my article.

I can view source under `View -> Source`. Can I edit source? It is not under `Edit`.

Comment: In a LaTeX document, the 'preamble' is the arbitrarily small or large number of lines between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`.  You can add *some* 'code' there, but not just anything you like.  More information is definitely needed, especially if you are using some sort of editor like `LyX`.

Answer (score 23):

LyX hides LaTeX Preamble under the menu option Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

[image]

Comment: If you add the line `\input{options}`, then you can outsource your custom preamble (e.g. all the packages you want to use, etc.) to the file `options.tex`, then you can reuse your preamble for several documents. I use this for a large lyx-document, which is chapter-wise divided into single lyx-files. So, I can compile the single chapters.

Comment: @mins: I can't replicate it. What version are you using? Perhaps connect with the LyX developers and give them the steps you took so they can replicate it.

Answer (score 8):

Your document should have the form:

```
\documentclass{<class>}

%% material here is the preamble

\begin{document}

%% material here is the body of the document

\end{document}
```

Typically, you would write something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{<your favorite package>}
\begin{document}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

There are various ways of structuring your document.  For example you might put your *preamble* in its own file---let's say it's called `my_preamble.tex`.  Then, you can load as

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \input{my_preamble}
 \begin{document}
 ...
 \end{document}
```

Whatever editor or IDE you're using to build your document, you should be able to manually modify the contents of the document to suit your needs.

Comment: I am using lyx.  If I want to add latex code directly, I go to insert -> latex code.  This does not let me get to the preamble.  This was the question.

Comment: @Artman Then you should add that information to your question.  I'm unfamiliar with `LyX`.  But `LyX` should nevertheless be creating a `<filename>.tex` source file.  You could open that up directly and enter what you want to your preamble.  Though, in that case, make sure you've not opened the same document in both `LyX` and the other editor.

Comment: Yeah you're write, I never even wrote the word Lyx.  Assumed I had mentioned that fact.  Thanks for the answers.