# How do I ensure that linebreaks in URLs occur at the right position?

Tags: formatting, lyx, line-breaking, urls

I am writing my survey report using `LyX`. In my bibliography section, there is unusual behavior in my `pdf.` One reference breaks the margin. This is the issue

[image]

You can see that one line is out of standard formatting. Why does this happen? Can I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know LyX that well, but you can fix that with the `url` package.  Research how to use `url` with LyX; the solution to that will solve your problem :)

Comment: But I think it is not related with url .

Comment: It looks like a file path, which is a type of URL (more properly called a URI these days)

Comment: where to put it in preamble?

Comment: Anywhere, really.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133681/17423.

Comment: I inserted `\usepackage{url}` in preamble. still the problem remains

Comment: That's not going to be enough.  Y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19378/discussion-between-user3892439-and-sean-allred).

Comment: How are you compiling the bibliography?  Are you using `bibtex` or `biblatex` or writing it by hand?

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX will refuse to break a 'word' if it contains, among a few other characters, a `/`. This has very solid reasoning that's outside the scope of this answer, but the `url` LaTeX package will handle these things very cleanly.

Instead of typing in the file path directly, use `Insert -> URL`.  This will (presumably) wrap the argument in `\url{<my text here>}` so that line breaks are made correctly.