# LyX - Changing Section Numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx

I'm really happy to try to get rid of ***MS Word*** once and for all.

So I start in the use of ***LateX***.

I translate a philosophical book from English to French that contains a lot of mathematical equations. (For those interested, this is the first volume of *Mario Bunge*'s ***Treatise on Basic Philosophy***.)

I use ***LyX*** on ***Windows*** with the ***AMS Book*** *document class*.

As the screenshot shows, the section is numbered ***1.1*** and the subsection is numbered ***1.1.1***.

Is there a *simple* way to have the section numbered ***1*** and the subsection numbered ***1.1*** instead. In other words, I would like to remove the number associated with the chapter at the beginning of each section and subsection.

Maybe there is already a *document class* that numbers this way?

Thanks,

François

A proud and new user of LaTeX

[image: Screenshot from LyX and AMS Book section numbering scheme]

Comment: If you don't have any chapters, try article documentclass (book is supposed to have chapters)... If you mean you want chapters I, II etc and not to be shown in the sectioning headers the answer is different

Comment: @koleygr: I want chaptier, section and subsection. I need chapter numbering like this: Chapter 1, 2, 3, etc., section numbering: 1. Section, 2. Section, etc., subsection numbering: 1.1 Subsection, 1.2 Subsection, etc.

Comment: Add these commands in your preamble: `\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}`. See here how: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133681/how-do-i-add-something-to-the-preamble-in-lyx

Comment: @FrançoisMaurice You might be interesting in joining the LyX mailing lists lyx-users and lyx-fr (francophone). Find more information here: https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133689/120578

And add the commands:

```
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

This will give you something like this:

[image]

**Edit about no subsections in the TOC:**

Add this line to under previous two:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost done, except that the subsection does not appear in the Contents as in your example: _2.1 First subsection_.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If you mean you have not subsections at all in toc, please let me know the documentclass you are using

Comment: I get this: Chapter 1

Comment: It is a matter of documentclass I suppose... Try some of them, like book, report... etc

Comment: Sorry for the comment. Here's the full comment: @koleygr I don't see in the table of contents (but in the body I see it), as in your example, the subsection like "2.1 First subsection".

Comment: Edited the answer to help you with this... Please consider accepting if it is ok.

Comment: You are right. It is a document class matter !! I'll try to find one which produce a table of contents with subsection.

Comment: I found a workaround. For an unknown reason to me, I have to modify "Numbering & TOC" in the document settings. Under "Appears in TOC" I have to say Yes to the Paragraph. After this I see the full table of contents. I think it is a bug.

Comment: Yes. It works fine. I add the line \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} to the Preamble and I get the full table of contents. Thanks a lot. :-)