# 'References' not in contents nor header in beamer?

Tags: beamer, lyx, presentations

Using LyX, I am wondering whether it's possible not to have 'references' in the header/contents in a beamer presentation?

Ex:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass beamer
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% for beamer version >= 3.5 only
%\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package auto
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plainnat
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 1
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title (Plain Frame)
Template beamer
\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset Argument 4
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Separator latexpar
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citet
key "king_matrix_2014"
literal "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Separator plain
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Frame
\begin_inset Argument 4
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Separator latexpar
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
btprint "btPrintCited"
bibfiles "C:/Users/a.fabre/Google Drive/Economie/Articles/Environment,C:/Users/a.fabre/Google Drive/Economie/Articles/test"
options "plainnatnourl_clean"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_deeper
\end_body
\end_document
```

The .tex exported from LyX:

```
%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% this default might be overridden by plain title style
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}
% plain title style, override default
\renewcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame[plain]{\maketitle}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% for beamer version >= 3.5 only
%\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Template beamer}
\makebeamertitle
\begin{frame}{}

\citet{king_matrix_2014}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{}

\bibliographystyle{plainnatnourl_clean}
\bibliography{\string"C:/Users/a.fabre/Google Drive/Economie/Articles/Environment\string",\string"C:/Users/a.fabre/Google Drive/Economie/Articles/test\string"}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: the first solution proposed works for the minimal example above, but not for my original file: https://pastebin.com/GxbY3XcZ

Comment: Hi, please edit your code to make it complete and compilable.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It's not really clear what you mean by 'references'. However, the appearance of a Beamer presentation is largely determined by the theme (here: Warsaw), you can change that to get a different look (see, e.g., http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `bibliography` creates its own section. To disable this you can add `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}` to your preamble (after loading the `natbib` and `babel` packages).

```
%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% this default might be overridden by plain title style
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}
% plain title style, override default
\renewcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame[plain]{\maketitle}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}
\begin{document}

\title{Bibliography not working}
\makebeamertitle


\begin{frame}{}
\citet{king_matrix_2014}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hu, I get two 'references' in the header instead of one by adding this to the latex preambule in LyX.

Comment: @bixiou Can you add the .tex file to the question that shows this problem?

Comment: I have just done it.

Comment: @bixiou Move it after `babel` like in my answer

Comment: But how can I do this on LyX?

Comment: @bixiou Sorry, no idea about lyx. maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133681/how-do-i-add-something-to-the-preamble-in-lyx helps?

Comment: @bixiou To force the `\renewcommand` to be executed after the `babel` package, you could try `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}}` instead of `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}`

Comment: @bixiou It is really strange that `babel` is loaded so late in your example. I would usually load it of one of the first packages, because many other packages will pick up its settings. For example `natbib` will adapt to whatever language is selected if it is loaded after the babel package.

Comment: Well, you should tell this to LyX developers^^

Comment: @bixiou Better Idea: I just tell the lyx users to use real tex instead of lyx :)

Comment: Well, I like the WYSIWYG side. Btw, your solution "AtBegin..." works !

Comment: @bixiou Good to hear it is working!

Comment: Well actually... it works only for the minimal example here, but not for my original beamer presentation :-(

Comment: @bixiou Then please add a .tex file to your question that is not working.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: @bixiou You still have `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}` in your preamble before `babel`

Comment: Yet, I put `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}}` exactly at the same place in LyX.

Comment: @bixiou Sorry, I must have followed an old link. I'll have a look

Comment: Ok for some obscure reason, it works now. I copy/pasted all the content of my non-working file in my working-file. Although the preambule were the same, there must have been something different that made things work

Comment: @bixiou Good to hear, than I'll stop digging through the mess lyx calls a preamble :)