# How to insert LaTeX preamble commands to a module in LyX?

Tags: lyx, modules

I am writing a LyX [module](https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules) that I want to have the following structute:

```
#\DeclareLyXModule{A module that handles amsthm}
#DescriptionBegin
#Defines theorem environments.
#DescriptionEnd

Format 66

Requires    amsthm

Input thms-envs.inc
```

and then inside `thms-envs.inc` I want to insert the following LaTeX code:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

What is the LyX module syntax to achieve that?

I know I can [simply go to the document settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133681/180429) and do that, but I want to do it using a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is to use `AddToPreamble` and `EndPreamble`. To insert the code you want, you could do the following:

```
AddToPreamble
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
  \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
  \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
EndPreamble
```

For more information, please see Help > Customization.